# How to show Video preview in my ionic html page. I have just Video URL from my web server

Tags: video, ionic4, cordova-media-plugin

I want to show my video preview to fetch Video URL just like http://url/videos/1234.mp4 from my web server. how to show video preview on my video.html page?

```
<video poster="{{review.videoPath}}" preload="auto">
  <source [src]="review.videoPath" type="mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I have not poster="{{review.videoPath}}" it's write when i follow a link.

Comment: _"...From my web server"_ any chance to put a testable video MP4 and poster JPG or PNG link? Does it work if you do a normal `<video>` tag with poster in HTML file?

Comment: Amm! I have not poster just video on the web browser.

Comment: Are you saying you put `poster="{{review.videoPath}}"` because it was written like that in some tutorial link?

Comment: Thanks I done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done with this. I can overlay my content and play/pasue video onclick.

```
<video #videoTag style="width: 100%; position: absolute;" [autoplay]="true (click)="videocontorl($event)" *ngIf="isShow"> 
    <source [src]="videoPath" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

Comment: I done with this. I can overlay my content and play/pasue video onclick.

<video #videoTag style="width: 100%; position: absolute;" [autoplay]="true (click)="videocontorl($event)" *ngIf="isShow"> 
    <source [src]="videoPath" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Mark as correct Answer by clicking big `✓` next to your message. This way others can know the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Does it work if you do a normal  tag with poster in HTML file?"*

This is what I meant...

```
<video loop controls="true" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%">
<source src="http://url/videos/1234.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```